# Use MonoGame in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, xna, windows-runtime, monogame

Can I mix MonoGame with XAML in WPF appliaction? For example: core of game written in MonoGame, but UI written in XAML and placed on top of MonoGame-Canvas. I know that I can use [XAML on MonoGame in WinRT](http://gamedevresources.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-xaml-on-monogame-for-winrt-part-2.html). Can I do same things in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read Nick Gravelyn's blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application.aspx

That should work for MonoGame as well, except for the last part that uses
the content build pipeline as MonoGame does not yet have its own content
build pipeline implementation.

You can find some samples here: https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples

Comment: There are also WPF examples that come with Monogame now. I use it myself and it works well.

Comment: A lot of water has run under the bridge since then, but here you go: https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples

Comment: Just for clarity, this old revision of MonoGame has a submodule reference to that repo: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/b0a31d8b1b4bae65328f2bf56aae17e5df78a744

Answer (score 1):

MonoGame 3.2 supports WPF/DirectX interop now. http://www.monogame.net/2014/04/07/monogame-3-2/